# Change Facebook connect button to my own image

Tags: jquery, css, facebook, button, customization

I'm using Facebook PHP SDK to login users to my website. But my problem is that I don't understand how I can change the button to my own button/image.

```
<div class="fb-login-button" onlogin="javascript:CallAfterLogin();" size="xlarge" scope="<?php echo $fbPermissions; ?>">Connect With Facebook</div>
```

This is how my code looks. But I want to show my image "connect.png" instead of the ugly standard button they give me.

Can you help me?

Love 
/Karl

Comment: I think modificate FB button is against their TOS

Comment: But I have seen a lot of sites with custom buttons.

Comment: Ok, so don't take my comment into account, i was not sure

Answer (score 2):

with the mentioned fb-login-button you can't specify your own image. But you can create your own link to the facebook login page (attached to a custom image). have a look here, how you can get your personal login url:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/